# How to initialize a QuerySnapshot type variable for a 1 document request to FireBase / Firestore with Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get documents from a collection with the method `FireBaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").where("name", isEqualTo : "something").get()` which used to have a return type of QuerySnapshot.

My goal is to make a ListView or anything that can display like a ListView the result(s) of this request.

I have these functions :

This one is to get the documents with the where method

```
class DataBaseMeth {
  getUserByUsername(String username) async{
    return fsInstance.collection("users").where("name", isEqualTo: username).get();

  }
}
```

This one is the widget with the result :

```
class SearchResultTile extends StatelessWidget {

  final String username;

  const SearchResultTile({
    Key? key,
    required this.username,

  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 25.0),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Column(
            children: [
              Text(
                username,
              ),//username

            ],
          ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And finally the class of the page :

```
class SearchPage extends StatefulWidget {...}

class _SearchPageState extends State<SearchPage> {

  DataBaseMeth dataBaseMethods = DataBaseMeth();
  TextEditingController usernameSearchController = TextEditingController();

  QuerySnapshot searchSnapshot; //the only way the code run is to replace the type by dynamic

  initSearch(){
    dataBaseMethods.getUserByUsername(usernameSearchController.text)
        .then((result){
          setState((){
            searchSnapshot = result;
            print("result : $searchSnapshot");
            //print("result : ${searchSnapshot.docs[1].data.toString()}");
          });
    });
  }

  Widget searchList(){
    return searchSnapshot != null ?
      ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: searchSnapshot.docs.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return SearchResultTile(
              username: searchSnapshot.docs[index].data.toString(),
              personalMessage: "personalMessage");
          }
      )
    :
      Container();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    searchList();
    super.initState();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: const MainAppBar(titleText: 'Search truc', mainPage: true),
      body: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0, vertical: 10.0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: TextField(
                    controller: usernameSearchController,
                    decoration: textFieldInputDecoration("search username..."),
                    style: whiteText(),
                  ),
                ),

                IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      initSearch();
                    },
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.search_outlined),
                    color: const Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
                    highlightColor: Colors.deepPurple,
                    splashColor: const Color(0xFF3A206B),
                    tooltip: "Search",
                ),
              ],
            ),

            searchList()


          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The result of the print of searchSnapshot (when I put it on dynamic) is :
*I/flutter (31401): result : Instance of '_JsonQuerySnapshot'*

And nothing appears when I tap on the button.

Answer (score 0):

Your `fsInstance.collection("users").where("name", isEqualTo: username).get()` returns a  `Future<QuerySnapshot>` not a `QuerySnapshot`, so that's why you can't assign it to `QuerySnapshot searchSnapshot`. You *can* assign it to `Future<QuerySnapshot> searchSnapshot` though.

That also means that if you want to use it in your UI you'll have to either wrap it in a `FutureBuilder` or pass it to `setState()`.